# Strange behaviour when writing/reading from a txt file in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a GUI for a minesweeper and I am saving the difficulty in a text file. However instead of writing to file the difficulty properly, it always empties the file and my null check condition is triggered.

I have tried using debugging and manually editing the text file to contain the string "HARD", but after changing the difficulty (setting it again to hard, or switching to easy), the file becomes empty.

```
public class MineSweeperMain extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        String difficulty;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LastProgramState.txt"));
            difficulty = br.readLine();
            if (difficulty == null) {
                System.out.println("???");
                throw new FileNotFoundException(); // If I comment this out, file becomes empty
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("LastProgramState.txt"));
            bw.write("EASY");
            bw.close();
            difficulty = "EASY";
        } finally {
        if (br != null)
        br.close();
        }

        int xSize;
        int ySize;
        int bombCount;
        System.out.println(difficulty);
        if (difficulty == null) {
            System.exit(200);
        }
        if (difficulty.equals("HARD")) {
            xSize = 16;
            ySize = 16;
            bombCount = 40;
        }
        else {
            xSize = 9;
            ySize = 9;
            bombCount = 10;
        }
            Menu menu1 = new Menu("Options");
            Menu menu2 = new Menu("Help");
            MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Difficulty: Easy");
            MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem("Difficulty: Hard");
            MenuItem mi3 = new MenuItem("How to play");
            MenuItem mi4 = new MenuItem("About...");
            menu1.getItems().add(mi1);
            menu1.getItems().add(mi2);
            menu2.getItems().add(mi3);
            menu2.getItems().add(mi4);

            MenuBar bar = new MenuBar();
            bar.getMenus().addAll(menu1,menu2);
            Label score = new Label("Score:");
            Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("MineSweeper");

            primaryStage.show();
}
            mi1.setOnAction(event -> { //EASY
            try {
                BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("LastProgramState.txt"));
                bwriter.write("EASY");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.exit(100);
            }
                primaryStage.close();
                Platform.runLater( () -> { //RUN APPLICATION AGAIN
                    try {
                        new MineSweeperMain().start( new Stage() );
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.exit(100);
                    }
                } );
            });
            mi2.setOnAction(event -> { //HARD
            try {
                BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("LastProgramState.txt"));
                bwriter.write("HARD");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.exit(100);
            }
                primaryStage.close();
                Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    try {
                        new MineSweeperMain().start( new Stage() );
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.exit(100);
                    }
                } );
            });
}
```

If I choose hard difficulty, I expect the txt file to contain the string "HARD", but instead it contains the string "EASY". The same behaviour occurs when I choose easy difficulty. Also I noticed that if I remove the throw new FileNotFoundException(), the file becomes completely empty. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Issue solved, I forgot to close the file after writing to in in  `mi1.setOnAction()` and `mi2.setOnAction()`.

Comment: *If I comment this out, file becomes empty* And when you throw your `FileNotFoundException` you write EASY. You should actually look at the exception instead of blindly writing EASY.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm sorry I don't get it, what do you mean?

Comment: `} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("LastProgramState.txt"));
            bw.write("EASY");
            bw.close();
            difficulty = "EASY";
        }` - what was `e`? You don't know. You ignored it. I can only assume your file is empty.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's exactly the problem, if the file is deleted, the program creates a new one, but when it is empty, the program fails to launch. Is there any exception that allows me to check if a file is empty, or should I read the contents and confirm if the string is null?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Also since the contents are empty, shouldn't the FileNotFoundException that is thrown trigger the catch block?

Comment: I suspect that you're not managing the resource correctly and leaving it "open" which may be preventing it from been written to.  Better to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure the resource is released correctly

Comment: @MadProgrammer Try-with-resources is a try catch block that saves me from the pain of using a finally block? Is it equivalent with try -> catch -> finally, or is there a difference? I saw netbeans recommending it to me, but I didn't know its purpose, so I decided to leave it out.

Comment: `File.exists()` and `File.canRead()` are a better solution to `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I see. Is there any difference between File.exists() and FileNotFoundException? Also off-topic, but how can I add code highlight in comments? Ctrl + K doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnM. It's different, in that it ensures that the resource is closed before the block exists. You can still use `finally` for other things, but this takes care of ensuring that any `Closable` elements are closed properly

Comment: Yes. `File.exists()` returns a boolean. Of course that's different from throwing an exception. Don't forget to also call `File.canRead()`. If the file exists, and you can read from it, then your code should not throw a `FileNotFoundException`. Otherwise, you know the file does not exist (or you can't read from it) and you can  follow a logical path for that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, useful advice, it will definitely be useful down the line. I also managed to solve the issue it was in mi1.setOnAction() and  mi2.setOnAction(). I actually forgot to close the file after writing to it. Duh...

Comment: 99% of the code posted has nothing to do with the question; please edit your question to remove all code not directly required to clarify your problem. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Bohemian Edited it. Is it ok now? I just want to leave it here in case someone has to deal with the same issue I did.

Comment: @john it’s better, but what does xSize and bombCount have to do with reading a file? Please aggressively edit the code to remove all but the very few lines that show the problem. Forget what the program does - it’s irrelevant. This question is about file I/O and file I/O only. Please have a good read of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).